# GSAP - How to adjust "to" parameters while the animation is in progress

Tags: javascript, three.js, gsap

I'm currently trying to *shoot* (move) little squares from one position to another. To achieve this, I am using Three.js for the drawing/rendering together with GSAP for the animations. My current code to perform the animation looks as follows:

```
gsap.to(obj.position, {
        duration: 1, 
        x: destinationObj.position.x, 
        y: destinationObj.position.y, 
        z: destinationObj.position.z, 
    })
```

It is possible that my destination object coordinates change during the animation. However, with my current code the object still *shoots* to the old coordinates, which doesn't look nice. Is there a way to continuously update the destination coordinates during the animation such that my objects adjust their course when necessary?